# Grouped search in Excel

Tags: excel

Say we have Column A in Excel with several IDs, which are repeating (i.e. are occurring in more than one row). Column B contains different strings.
I want to create Column C which contains TRUE, if a certain string (say ABC) occurs in Column B **at least one time** over the grouped IDs in Column A.
I do not want to explicitly write the ID in the formula and pull the formula down manually over all rows, in which one certain ID occurs, as I want to keep it generic.

As there is no `GROUPBY` function in Excel I do not know how to do a grouped search.

Answer (score 0):

What about the approach I made in following screenshot:

[image: Excel screenshot]

For your information, these are the used formulae:

- in C2 : `=A2 & "|" & B2`
- in D2 : `=COUNTIF(C$2:C$15, C2)`
- in E2 : `=IF(D2=1, FALSE, TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks for your response! This is close to what I am looking for but I want Column E to display TRUE over all rows if a certain value in Column B occurs at least one time within an ID. I.e. in your example: We want to look for value 1 in Column B. The cell in Row 4 and Column E should also display TRUE for ID a1, as value 1 occurred at least one time in Column B for this ID.

Comment: @TRausch: you mean: I close, but no cigares :-)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your intent, because the condition: at **least one time** will be always `TRUE`, because any value you put at least will be one time. It would need some clarification. Anyway I will provide the logic. In cell `C1` you can use the following formula (assuming no excel version constraint):

```
=MAP(A1:A7,B1:B7, LAMBDA(gr,str, SUM((A1:A7=gr) * (B1:B7=str))))>0
```

**Note**: You can use `COUNTIFS` too.

```
=MAP(A1:A7,B1:B7, LAMBDA(gr,str, COUNTIFS(A1:A7,gr, B1:B7, str)))>0
```

Here the output:
[image: excel output]